Two connections on a smooth $SO(3)$-vector bundle
Let $E\to M$ be a smooth oriented real vector bundle of rank 3, so that its structure group can be reduced to $SO(3)$. Suppose $E\to M$ is given a Riemannian metric and a connection $\nabla:\Omega^0(E)\to \Omega^1(E)$ compatible to it.
Consider its endomorphism bundle $\text{End}(E)$. $\nabla$ induces a connection (also denoted by $\nabla$) on $\text{End}(E)$ satisfying $(\nabla \phi)(\sigma)=\nabla(\phi(\sigma))-\phi(\nabla\sigma)$ (cf. exterior covariant derivative of $\operatorname{End}(E)$-valued $p$-form).
Now consider the adjoint bundle $\text{Ad}(E)$ of $E$. The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}\subset \text{End}(\Bbb R^3)$ of $SO(3)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^3$, via the isomorphism $\Bbb R^3\to \mathfrak{g}$, $v\mapsto (v\times -)$, where $\times $ is the cross product of $\Bbb R^3$. This gives an isomorphism $E\to \textrm{Ad}(E)$. Also the connection $\nabla$ on $\text{End}(E)$ defined above restricts to a connection on $\text{Ad}(E)$.
So now we have two connections on $E\cong \text{Ad}(E)$ (denoted by the same symbol). But are these two the same? It seems quite natural to be the same, but I'm not sure

Yes, they are the same.
More formally, the section $c\in\Gamma\mathrm{Hom}(E,\mathrm{Ad}(E))$ defined by $c(\sigma)(\tau)=\sigma\times\tau$ is parallel with respect to the induced connection, which means that for all $\sigma\in\Gamma E$
$$
\nabla \,c(\sigma)=c(\nabla\sigma)
$$
This is equivalent to the fact that
$$
\nabla(\sigma\times\tau)=\nabla\sigma\,\times\tau+\sigma\times\nabla\tau
$$
for all $\sigma,\tau\in\Gamma E$. To show this, fix $p\in M$ and a local positively oriented orthonormal frame $e_0,e_1,e_2$ with ${\nabla e_i}_{|p}=0$ and write $\sigma=\sigma^ie_i$, $\tau=\tau^ie_i$ using the double summation convention. Now consider indices modulo $3$, so that $e_{i}\times e_{i+1}=e_{i+2}$. Then at $p$
$$
\nabla(\sigma\times\tau)
=\nabla(\sigma^i\tau^{i+1}e_{i+2}-\sigma^i\tau^{i+2}e_{i+1})\\
=(d\sigma^i)\tau^{i+1}e_{i+2}-(d\sigma^i)\tau^{i+2}e_{i+1}+\sigma^i(d\tau^{i+1})e_{i+2}-\sigma^i(d\tau^{i+2})e_{i+1}\\
=\nabla\sigma\,\times\tau+\sigma\times\nabla\tau
$$
